# Increase time out for ws reqsuest from 1 min to 3 min angular nginx

Tags: nginx, timeout, httpclient, wildfly

I have an issue (504 Gateway Time-out) related to increase timeout from 1 to 3 or 4 minutes.Either after added nginx.conf timeout configuration( keepalive_timeout  1200s, proxy_send_timeout 1200s,proxy_read_timeout 1200s,    fastcgi_send_timeout 1200s,fastcgi_read_timeout 1200s) under location /rest/services and add the config "timeou": 360000 under file configuration proxy.conf.json the default value still the same 1 minutes.

angular code part :
const httpOptions = {
responseType: 'blob' as 'json',
};
let response= this.httpClient.post(BASE_PATH+"/cars/zippedfilecar",this.getActionPayload().data,httpOptions);

```
    response.pipe(timeout(400000)).subscribe((data) => {
      let blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/json'});

      var downloadURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = downloadURL;
        link.download = this.form.value.Type+"Cars.zip";
        link.click();
  });
```

also by changing the time out by set timeout at ws request didnt match , the timeout value change if i set value under 1min and none more than one minute

Ps: My front application deployed under cloud nginx, my backend application under server application wildfly19 .

any idea please ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10QRQ.png)